# Need Help - First Function

Tags: function, powershell, scripting, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to write my first function and am having some issues.  When I run the below I get no output.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I'm not sure what.

```
function findModifiedFiles {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [string]$dir,
        [int]$days
    )
    Process {
        Write-Host "Directory: " $dir
        Write-Host "Days: "$days
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Your function is never called. To run it like this, you should load the function first and then call it. First, `. .\modfilesTest.ps1`. Then `findModifiedFiles -dir c:\temp -days 7`.

Comment: You're not calling the function anywhere in your script file, so no wonder there is no output.. Just open the Powershell editor, paste the function in there and beneath that, call it with `findModifiedFiles -dir 'c:\temp' -days 7`. Then hit `F5` or click the green play button. BTW. Try and google for `powershell function naming convention` so you can write functions using **Verb-Noun**.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  I knew it was something noob.

Comment: When I copy/paste the function it allows me to use it but if I try to run the ps1 and then use the function I receive this error:

https://i.imgur.com/uEMOkqa.png

Comment: @poisedforflight That is because you need to dot source your function first. Notice the dot space before the relative path of the filename --> `. .\modfilesTest.ps1`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works.  What is the first `.` doing?

Comment: [about_operators / Dot sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#dot-sourcing-operator-)

Comment: @poisedforflight, It is the dot sourcing operator. It runs your script in the current scope and therefore loads any functions it defines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ultimately need to load your function and then call the function to receive any output. Since your function is defined in a file, one way to load the function is by [dot sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#dot-sourcing-operator-) the file. Then you can simply call your function.

```
. .\modfilesTest.ps1
findModifiedFiles -dir c:\temp -days 7
```

---

An alternative is to not use a function at all just run the script with parameters. If we edit your file to contain the following, we can just call the script afterwards.

```
# modfilesTest.ps1 Contents
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [string]$dir,
    [int]$days
)
Process {
    Write-Host "Directory: " $dir
    Write-Host "Days: "$days
}
```

Now call the script with your parameters.

```
.\modfilesTest.ps1 -dir c:\temp -days 7
```

---

A third alternative is to just paste a function definition into your console. At that point, the function is loaded into your current scope. Then you can just call the function.